# Overloading checks

Tags: personal-check

I recently went to the bank to deposit several thousand checks I saved up.
They refused, told me to contact corporate.
Is this normal? Do banks have some limit on accepting huge amounts of checks for a personal account?
I'm pretty sure a normal bank branch only processes a few checks a day so any more would be overwhelming.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure a normal bank branch only processes a few checks a day so any more would be overwhelming."  No, but any one teller can only process one at a time.

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but I've got to ask: how do you save up **several thousand** checks?

Comment: A proprietorship I ran.

Comment: Businessmen (and women) regularly deposit checks so they get money in the bank.

Comment: Over what time period did you save these checks? What country is this in? Why would you deposit business proceeds to a personal account?

Comment: USA, a few months, and idm

Comment: @RonBeyer if it's a sole proprietorship, then depositing business checks into a personal account is perfectly legal (though unwise).

Comment: @RonJohn I didn't mean to suggest it was illegal, I was a small business owner for 10+ years... It is very unwise though.

Comment: @RonBeyer exactly.  Which is why he *ran* a proprietorship.

Comment: If you are taking in that many checks, you should get a deposit terminal for your business. You really shouldn't hold on to checks, just from a business perspective your customers expect you to deposit in a timely manner. It also exposes you to a lot of potential rejected checks and fees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *teller* may have a limit on how many checks that he or she can process, but an entire bank can get thousands of checks per day from businesses that make daily deposits. There may also be a limit on *personal* accounts; you may need to set up a business account that includes check processing (probably not for free).

I would to what they say - talk to the branch manager first and see what they recommend. They should give you the name of someone in "corporate" that you can contact to help you deposit those checks. If you get nowhere, try a different bank. They may want you to open a new account, and may not process all of the checks for free.

That said, they might be wary of this being some sort of fraud since it is very unusual, so you may have to do some convincing that this is legitimate (assuming it is, of course...)

Comment: So is it normal for a bank to see a stack of checks and balk? Is it really just physically impossible for a teller to handle a ton of checks in a day?

Comment: I can imagine that a teller wouldn't have time to process thousands of checks individually. I know some banks use companies with special equipment to process large batches of checks electronically; I doubt that tellers have access to such equipment and must process them one at a time. Even a quick scanner that takes 10 seconds would take almost 3 hours to process 1,000 checks, and that's time that is not spent doing their "regular" job.

Answer (score 2):

> Do banks have some limit on accepting huge amounts of checks for a
> personal account?

You have to check with your bank regarding limits on personal accounts.

- They can limit the number of checks.
- They can put a hold on the money if the amount is over a daily limit.
- They can limit the number or size of transactions deposit by ATM
- They can limit the number or amount deposited on a daily basis vie remote deposit systems.

The bank does have another way, they can require you to use a business account. The fee structure and limits of a business account will be different.

Answer (score 1):

If checks are small - I would suggest to try Mobile Check Deposit offered by your banks Mobile App.

Comment: For several *thousand* checks? I guess this at least would make the OP realize how onerous a task they were asking the poor teller to perform.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely unusual for an individual to have thousands of checks.  So the chances are that they either think you are involved in some scam, or else are running a business through a personal account.

It sounds like you are going to contact their HQ to explain why you are trying to process so many checks in one go.